# Visual Studio "code alignment" extension not working

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting, visual-studio-extensions

I am using visual studio 2013, I am using an extension called ["Code Alignment"](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd/). After I apply the alignment and try to beautify the code, the visual studio removes the alignment.

I already checked the options in:

Option > Text Editor:

- Tabs
- Keep tabs

Do you have a solution for this?

ie:

before formatting:

```
var previousLowAddress    = new string[1];
var previousMedAddresses  = new string[1];
var previousHighAddresses = new string[1];
```

after visual studio formatting:

```
var previousLowAddress = new string[1];
var previousMedAddresses = new string[1];
var previousHighAddresses = new string[1];
```

Comment: Why don't you use visual studio built-in alignment shortcuts?

Comment: I think you can take a look here ..http://www.codealignment.com/ForVisualStudio.html ..

Comment: [There's a good reason why they do it](https://medium.com/@fagnerbrack/why-aligning-statements-will-haunt-you-c7385a3b24d).

Comment: Thanks sir @Fagner

Comment: Problem with his argument, is that it can be applied to literally any formatting, so much so he had to post this.
https://medium.com/@fagnerbrack/indentation-and-alignment-can-help-you-89e7e1b8bdff

Answer (score 0):

VS has auto formatting enabled by default for c#. The options are in Text Editor\C#\Formatting.

You may need to disable all option in these category.

The productivity power tools extension also has a feature which formats the document on save. So if you use these extension you may disable the feature.

The built-in c# auto formatting honors indenting assignments, but if you try to indent round brackets/operators (as code alignment does), the extra whitespace will be removed by formatting.

[image]

Comment: If you issue a format command, obviously vs will format your code. Just type your example again, and do not format your code. There is no option to turn off formatting completely.

Comment: Thanks @apr,i think i will leave it that way

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is the font you are using is not ["monospaced"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). This means different characters can take different amount of space, which will break the math the CodeAlignment plugin will do for you.

Try changing the Text Editor font to a monospaced type, such as "Consolas".

I tested this locally using Consolas and Microsoft YaHei UI fonts. As expected, the monospaced font (consolas) shows the correct alignment, and the Proportional font (Microsoft YaHei UI) does not.

[image]

Comment: This was it for me! In VS-Code you can see what font is actually being used by opening the web inspector ("Help" -> "Toggle Developer Tools"). Change font in user settings to something monospace ("Source Code Pro" in my case) and code alignment works!